# retrieving user information from OpemAM

Tags: opensso, openam

I have successfully setup OpenAM and j2ee policy agent to do my sso, authentication and authorization. Now want my java application thats being protected to have the ability to access information of the currently logged user (user name and group for eg.)

Answer (score 0):

We can use the openam REST API to get these values:

https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13/dev-guide#rest-api-crud-identity

openam/json/users/_action=